# how to calculate the working days in between two different dates in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have two textbox using calaendarExtender and one label.

My needed is if i select two different dates in calendar extender the number of working days(excluding Sunday) to be automatically display in the label.

can any one help me.....
im new in ASP.net......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 12, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 12, 31);

int workdays = 0;
DateTime aux = start;
while(aux <= end)
{
    aux = aux.AddDays(1);
    if (aux.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        workdays++;
}
yourLabel.Text = workdays.ToString();
```